# Android - Drag and Crop issues

Tags: android

I'm trying my hand at some simple photo manipulation on an image at the top of an `activity` within an `ImageView`, which on average has a `200dp` height and matches the width of its parent.

I have implemented a custom `onTouchListener` class, which creates a `matrix` and translates the image within the `ImageView`

**Drag**:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
     if (mode == DRAG) {
        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
        matrix.postTranslate(v.getX(), event.getY() - start.y);
     }
     break;
```

This works perfectly, it drags the image on the *y axis* only. But when the user releases I want the image to crop down to the bounds of the visible `ImageView` area.

**Crop**:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
     if (mode == DRAG) {
        Bitmap bitmap = drawableToBitmap(view.getDrawable());
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
        view.setImageBitmap(result);
      }
      break;
```

This crops the image to the right size, but only from the top of background of the imageview not the visible boundaries. With the call to the `Bitmap` class function `createBitmap(int x, int y, int width, int height)` my only assumption would be `view.getTop()` is making it start at the top.

So, my question is: How could I calculate the difference between the top of the visible view bounds and the background/matrix boundaries?

[image: The dark blue area is the ImageView]

Note: The image displays an image (blue) which is located at the top of an Activity (the cyan looking areas are just the background invisible boundaries of the `ImageView`, not the activity)

I would like to emphasize that I don't wish to use any third party libraries to achieve this.

I'm more than willing to provide additional code, if need be.

Update:

Full `onTouch` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    // Dump touch event to log
    dumpEvent(event);

    // Handle touch events here...
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(v.getX(), event.getY());
            mode = DRAG;
            originalY.y = (int) event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
             if (mode == DRAG) {
        Bitmap bitmap = drawableToBitmap(view.getDrawable());
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
        view.setImageBitmap(result);
      }
      break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == DRAG) {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                matrix.postTranslate(v.getX(), event.getY() - start.y);
            }
            break;
    }
    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    return true; // indicate event was handled
}
```

Comment: in your screen Shot , any bitmap you set in Background in Whole Screen or do you set any height , I know you have put 200dp but i thinks its visible area of image that should be cropped on button click , so if you provide me your screen information with actual image then i would defiantly help you ..

Comment: The image inside the imageview would be cropped to the width of the screen and maintains the height based on it being cropped (normal scale cropping), then the user can drag as much space the height of the original image provides, it would be any image (that minimum fit the width of the screen). The only thing that is fixed in this, is the height of the imageview itself, the matrix size is dynamic, which means the distance between the matrix top and imageview top is also dynamic

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the root height of the Activity, we can use

```
int height = this.getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
```

or you can use display metrics as

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Or add a global layout listener

```
ViewTreeObserver vtObserver = view.getViewTreeObserver();
vtObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    // check if the view's height and/or width > 0
    // don't forget to remove the listener when done using removeOnGlobalLayoutListener
}
```

});

Comment: Please re-read the question. I'm looking for the boundaries between the visible ImageView area (blue) (and the value of the boundaries of the top of that visible area to the top of the background/matrix boundaries (cyan)). There will be plenty of widgets within the Activity below the ImageView so getting the activity's height is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

The code lacks some context but I assume that when user starts dragging you create new `savedMatrix` and `start` point and update them every time onTouchListener is called or else I don't understand how your code works at all.

If so it means that you actually have the translation you need in the `savedMatrix`, so why don't get it right from there? I think what you need is something like

```java
int top = savedMatrix.getValues()[Matrix.MTRANS_Y]
```

I haven't checked it and don't know internal structure of `Matrix` well enough, so you might need to invert the sign of the `top`.

**Sidenote**: It is not clear why in `matrix.postTranslate(v.getX(), event.getY() - start.y);` you pass `v.getX()` there. Probably it works OK just because `v.getX()` is always 0 in your scenario.